# Can I use startActivityOnResult even if it is deprecated?

Tags: java, android, startactivityforresult

OnActivityResult and startActivityAtResult method is deprecated in android studio.Is there any way of using this method instead of using  new method?
If yes then how?

Comment: Yes, you can use it as always.

Comment: Yes you can but it might stop working in near future

Comment: but how do i make it more? because whatever i type in there appears in red. Please tell me an exact solution of how to make it work

Comment: `startActivityAtResult ` was now replaced by `registerForActivityResult`